# How do you show help for a parameter in an ArcGIS python toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, raster, python-toolbox

I have created a python toolbox, the interface is shown below:

[image: My tool]

How do you edit the parameter description so that when you click in the boxes, a relevant description will show up in the tool help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a description to the parameter which shows up in the help panel by editing the *Item Description* of the tool.

Right click on your tool and select Item Description

[image: Setting Item Description]

You then add text to each parameter under the syntax section.

[image: Syntax section]